# How can I confirm ownership of my domain by creating a DNS record?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, dns, domain

I am trying to set up a custom email domain for my partner's personal website at `sanchezgomez.info` using outlook.com.

I am trying to [follow these instructions](http://www.blogsynthesis.com/setup-microsoft-outlook-custom-domain/). Here's what I've done and where I'm getting stuck;

1. Go to domains.live.com
2. Sign in, click on *Get Started*
3. enter the domain name `sanchezgomez.info`, choose *Set up Outlook.com for my domain* and click *Continue*
4. Attempt and fail Microsoft's human-proof bot tester before eventually guessing right
5. I am then taken to the *Domain settings* page, shown in the image below. I enter the MX server settings on the domain registrar and click *Continue* but it just takes me back to this same page.

I have waited over 12 hours now and it is still not recognizing the change. The record shows up exactly as intended at [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx:sanchezgomez.info&run=toolpage), but for some reason microsoft isn't recognising it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quite enter the MX record correctly.  When you enter a DNS entry, if you do not suffix the entry with a `.` your domain name will be appended to the end.  This is how your MX record looks now:

```
sanchezgomez.info.      3599    IN      MX      10 f926f850ac5343a397ddfd471f0d49.pamx1.hotmail.com.sanchezgomez.info.
```

Whereas you want it to look like

```
sanchezgomez.info.      3599    IN      MX      10 f926f850ac5343a397ddfd471f0d49.pamx1.hotmail.com.
```

When you enter the `f926f850ac5343a397ddfd471f0d49.pamx1.hotmail.com.` entry, make sure you keep the `.` on the end.

Comment: I **just** realised that and was about to remove the post. But thank you!